# How to use/capture Primevue's Tabview component's "tab-change" event in vue3 composition API?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api, tabview, primevue

What I have read in Primevue documentation, does not seem enough to figure it out. I did not find adequate examples at all, and the docs only says:

Primevue docs about the issue

[image: 1]

Can someone help me out? I am stuck.

Comment: any solution yet

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope this example helps, please comment if you need more information:

```html
<template>
<div>
    <TabView @tab-change="onTabChange">
        <TabPanel header="A"></TabPanel>
        <TabPanel header="B"></TabPanel>
    </TabView>
</div>
</template>

<script setup>
function onTabChange(event) {
    console.log(event)
}
</script>
```